# LWC AfterRender Error for any component

Tags: lightning-web-components

We are getting the error when we Edit any page with Lightning web components. Also, the pages with LWCs are blank. Any idea? This working perfectly fine till last week and all of a sudden showing this behavior from today. [image: Af]

Update: Issue is happening only in Chrome browser. No clue on what could be the issue.

Update: After uninstalling and reinstalling Chrome browser, issue resolved.

Comment: kind of hard to tell without seeing your lwc

Comment: It just uploaded the "LWC Recipes" package (available through Trailhead). Nothing more than that.

Comment: which code snipet from the lwc recipes?

Comment: everything :) basically once i ve installed the LWC Recipes app, I could just see the tabs. But everything is blank inside the tabs. This is happening only in Chrome browser. Very strange!

Comment: i'm affraid there aint much i can hep with =/

Comment: @wesfaith "Community Page Optimizer" conflict with lightning pages since the last patch release. Could you try to disable the extension?

Comment: Also @wesfaith - check the [closed issues for that repository](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aclosed) probably worth posting there

Comment: So I finally uninstalled and reinstalled Chrome browser and everything started working.   @pmdartus.. pretty sure it is because of some extension that I had..